# Solder is getting 'pasty' when heated

Tags: soldering

I am not an expert at soldering but I am good enough for simple tasks.  I am trying to solder some wires to a PCB.

If I use some 'old' solder (Radio Shack, 60/40 Rosin-core) I get a result that is acceptable to me.  Good flow of solder, shiny result, good connection.

If I use a 'new' solder (63/37 Rosin Core, Flux 1.8%) I do not get anything good at all.  The solder gets pasty, does not flow, does not stick.

I am using the same soldering iron, the same temperature (370C) and the same technique. The 'new' solder is thinner (0.8mm) than the old one.

What can I do to correct this?  Thanks.

Comment: Try 320C instead.

Comment: 370 seems really high. You might be burning off the flux before it can work.

Comment: That is odd because 63/37 is easier to work with than 60/40. 63/37 melts at a slightly lower temperature and flows easier. 63/37 does not have a plastic stage like 60/40. Sure, you don't have the two mixed up. When you say pasty, it sure sounds like a 60/40 plastic stage.

Comment: Is this chipquick??  Chipquick is a bit different.

Comment: You're sure the solder isn't counterfeit right? Some cheap solders cut it with a higher amount of lead which raises the melting temperature. Try adding external flux.

Answer (score 1):

I've run across this exact issue. I had some old radioshack rosin core 60/40 solder I used for many years and worked great. Last year I ran out and got a new brand that was highly recommended on forums and was about 60/40 again, but the new stuff was way worse at flowing and sticking to the metal. I don't have a good explanation for why the new stuff was different, but I can tell you that for me the solution in my case was to:

- Increase temperature of iron to about 400 C
- Hold the iron a bit longer on the base metal (ideally at the junction of the two base metals simultaneously) prior to introducing solder so you get good flow. The solder won't flow onto the base metal and make a nice shiny volcano unless the base metal gets hot enough.

Answer (score 0):

If the solder is from a Chinese company and it forms a sludge when "melted", it is likely counterfeit.

Tin is significantly more expensive than lead -- 15 to 20 times more expensive. Fake 60/40 solder has a higher percentage of lead than the advertised 40%.

The melting point of genuine 60/40 solder is \$188^{\circ}\$. At that temperature it melts completely and shouldn't be pasty. A soldering iron of sufficient size at \$200^{\circ}\$ should melt solder. If the soldering iron is not large enough, the solder should melt completely with an iron at some higher temperature, such as \$250^{\circ}\$ or \$300^{\circ}\$. But at whatever temperature is required to melt the 60/40 solder, it should melt completely. You should not need a iron temperature of \$350^{\circ}\$ unless the iron is small, or the solder diameter is large.

Counterfeit solder will be pasty. Part of it will melt, but part of it will remain solid, because the ratio of tin to lead is incorrect.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8cCja0FsYUs

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Ku7I3hA3AA

Comment: Thank you.  This is exactly what I am experimenting.  I will try to find something better on Amazon.